# How to compare values with the same ID but different other attribute?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, having-clause

```
+------+------+------+
| ID   |letter|number|
+------+------+------+
|1     |A     | 23   |
+------+------+------+
|1     |B     | 45   |
+------+------+------+
|2     |A     | 37   |
+------+------+------+
|2     |B     | 24   |
+------+------+------+
|2     |C     | 26   |
+------+------+------+
|3     |A     | 47   |
+------+------+------+
|3     |C     | 35   |
+------+------+------+
```

Noob here

I want to find all instances where the number for a given ID is smaller when the letter is A than it is when the letter is B. For example, when ID is 1, number for A is 23 and number for B is 45. Since 23 < 45, it fits the criteria, and I would like to return the ID 1 as well as the sum of the two numbers (23 + 45). ID = 2 does not work because 37 is not less than 24. ID = 3 also does not work because it doesn't have an entry with letter B.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: @nbk I'm using MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation in a `having` clause:

```
select id, sum(number) number_total
from mytable
where letter in ('A', 'B')
group by id
having min(case when letter = 'A' then number end) < min(case when letter = 'B' then number end)
```

This assumes that `(id, letter)` tuples are unique in the table. Otherwise you maybe want `SUM()` instead of `MIN()`.

If you wanted to display the values as well, then MySQL lets you use aliases in the `having` clause:

```
select 
    id, 
    sum(number) number_total,
    min(case when letter = 'A' then number end) number_a,
    min(case when letter = 'B' then number end) number_b
from mytable
where letter in ('A', 'B')
group by id
having number_a < number_b
```